# Xamarin.Forms how to store images - best practices

Tags: .net, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm creating app using Xamarin.Forms both for android and iOS. In my app I have a lot of images, for now I don't have server for backend and storing all images and then downloading them via application. All images are stored in app.
I have a two options:

- store images as resources in shared library
- store images in android and iOS project

As I said earlier I have more than 200 images and my question is: What is the best approach to storing images in Xamarin.Forms? Is any loading speed difference between storing images as resources in shared project and separate in each platform?

Android require at least 5 different sizes, iOS 3 so I have to create 8 different copies of the same image...

If I will store image in shared library, what size should I pick? Will be difference in performance between devices with small and big screen during scalling images?

Comment: Hi, although not suggesting that store large numbers of images in local, but if have no choose you can strore them in android and iOS project. This will be recommadned. Because each of native platform has cache folder that can accommodate large size of files to be stored. And that will show best performance in each native platform.

Comment: Also note that Android doesn't "require" the 5 different. It simply allows you to add them. If it doesn't find image for the screen size it'll just look up the chain. You only have to specify one. I think iOS may work the same.

Comment: @Andew I know, but I read that there is better performance where where Android don't have to scale image, that's why I want to have all sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can have svg images as embeddedresource in .netStandard porject, which will work for all android and iOS resolutions.

Comment: Ok, but what about performance? It will help with images amount but will render as fast as normaln png or slower?